# Understanding boolean operations in R

Tags: r, boolean

Why does the following operation result in  a non-boolean result?

```
sum <- TRUE + FALSE
sum
[1] 1
```

How can I get the result in boolean?

Comment: Use the operator `|` or `&` according to what you want

Comment: What is your desired result?

Comment: The question does not compute... What do you want to find out? You should not sum Boolean states.

Comment: I would like to know why the result is not in boolean?

Comment: The value `1` is logically equivalent to `TRUE` in many places in the R language (and `0` corresponds to `FALSE`).  Tell us what your goal is, and maybe we can help you.

Comment: It's boolean as mentioned above. `1`==`TRUE, `0`==`FALSE`.  Also please don't use names like `sum`.

Comment: Just do `as.logical(TRUE + FALSE)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In R, the numeric representation of `logical()` values is 0 and 1 for `FALSE` and `TRUE` respectively.  As you are adding these, they're being implicitly converted to numbers so `TRUE+TRUE` will return 2 and `TRUE-TRUE` will return 0.

If you're looking to have a logical result, use a logical operator `|` or `&`.

**Note** that R differentiates between vectorized logical operators and scalar.  `|` and `&` are meaningful for a set: `c(FALSE,FALSE,TRUE) & c(TRUE,FALSE,TRUE)` will return `c(FALSE,FALSE,TRUE)`.  Whereas `c(FALSE,FALSE,TRUE) && c(TRUE,FALSE,TRUE)` will return just `FALSE`.

To explicitly convert to logical, you can use `as.logical(TRUE + FALSE)` toreturn logical output in non-numeric form.